# How do i stop expo from running in the web

Tags: react-native, expo

I recently started react-native, after installing all dependencies i tried starting my project but when it starts i don"t seem to find the QR code scanner for me to scan with my device anywhere, instead it starts in the browser, it says
web  Starting Webpack on port 19006 in development mode.

- Expo Webpack █████████████████████████ building (40%) 194/196 modules 2 active
  node_modules\invariant\browser.js

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:19006/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\webpack-config\web-default
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /

. I want expo to run on my device not the browser.

Comment: Same thing happening with me while using React Navigation, I just noticed if I use version "@react-navigation/native": "5.6.1", Its fine but when you don't mention version by default its installing 5.7.X which is the issue in my  case.

Comment: so what do you suggest I do?

Comment: If you are using React Navigation try with the version I mentioned above. If not you can try adding dependencies one by one and see which dependency is having issue.

Comment: oh thanks that helped

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 6):

Try

1. Deleting all the `metro` packages from `project_root/node_modules`.
2. Run `npm install` in  `project_root`.
3. Now run `expo start` again and it should work.

This seems to help in most cases

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.json` you can set wich platforms you want, like this

```
"platforms": [
    "android",
    "ios"
 ]
```

Comment: It’s still the same thing

Comment: It says “expo web is in beta, please report any bugs or missing features on the expo repo.” I don’t remember opting for any expo web

Comment: Are you sure your app.json look like this ?

`{
  "expo": {
    "name": "awesome-expo-web-example",
    "slug": "awesome-expo-web-example",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    ...
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is :

When you use react-native-web, Metro uses webpack to pack your code to be
available for web.

Something is wrong with the installation (a bug maybe) so metro
cannot pack for running the code on a simulator or on a device.

The simptom is you cannot see the QR Code when npm start  wright ?

The Solution :  Customize webpack   https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-webpack/

This procedure creates the file webpack.config.js on the roor directory of your project.

Running the expo customize:web will create webpack.config.js

This action solves the problem.  You will see the QR again and
will be able to run your app in a device, simulator and web.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after installing some packages, and i did `npm install` and it worked